# Powershell: How to remove all files in Directory except recent ones

Tags: powershell, skip

Have folder which has backups of SQL databases with backup date in the name.
e.g. C:\Backup folder.
Example of backup files:
archive_1_01022022.bak
archive_1_02022022.bak
archive_1_03022022.bak
archive_2_01022022.bak
archive_2_02022022.bak
archive_2_03022022.bak
archive_3_01022022.bak
archive_3_02022022.bak
archive_3_03022022.bak

I need powershell script which removes all files from this directory but keeps recent ones (e.g. for last 5 days), but at the same time I need to keep at least 3 copies of each database (in case there are no backups done for more than last 5 days).

Below script removes all files and keeps recent ones for last 5 days:

```
$Folder = "C:\Backup"
$CurrentDate = Get-Date 
$DateDel = $CurrentDate.AddDays(-5) 
Get-ChildItem $Folder | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $DateDel } | Remove-Item
```

Above is wokring fine, but if there are no recent backups for last 10 days and if I run above code then it will remove all files in C:\Backup. For such cases I need to keep at least 3 backup files of each databases.

If I use below code (for example I have 9 different databases), then it do job:

```
$Folder = "C:\Backup"
Get-ChildItem $Folder | ? { -not $_.PSIsContainer } |
Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending |  
Select-Object -Skip 27 | 
Remove-Item -Force
```

But implementation is weird. For example if I have backups of 9 databases, then I need to provide "Select-Object -Skip" with value **27** (9 databases x skip 3 files of each database). In case I have more databases or less, then each time I need to adjust this number. How can I make "Select-Object -Skip **3**" static value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basing on the assumption that your backups have a name convention of : `DBNAME_ddMMyyyy.bak` where the date correspond to the backup date, I would do something like below.

```
$Params = @{
    MinBackupThresold = 1
    MinBackupDays = 5
    SimulateDeletion = $False # Set to true to perform a Remove-Item -WhatIf deletion}


$Folder = "C:\temp\test"
$CurrentDate = Get-Date 
$DateDel = $CurrentDate.AddDays($Params.MinBackupDays).Date # set to midnight


$Archives = Foreach ($File in  Get-ChildItem $Folder ) {
    # -13 come from assuming naming convention DBName_8CharBackupDate.ext (eg: Db1_01012022.bak)
    $DbNameEndIndex = $File.Name.Length - 13
    # +1 since our naming convention have an underscore between db name and date.
    $RawDateStr = $File.Name.Substring($DbNameEndIndex + 1 , 8)
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Path = $FIle.FullName
        LastWriteTime = $File.LastWriteTime
       DBName        = $File.Name.Substring(0, $DbNameEndIndex)
       BackupDate    = [datetime]::ParseExact( $RawDateStr, 'ddMMyyyy', $null)
    }
}

#Here we group archives by their "dbname" so we can make sure to keep a min.  backups for each.
$GroupedArchives = $Archives | Group DBName
Foreach ($Db in $GroupedArchives) {

    if ($Db.Count -gt $Params.MinBackupThresold) {
        $Db.Group | Sort BackupDate | Select-Object -Skip $Params.MinBackupThresold | Where-Object { $_.BackupDate -lt $DateDel } | % { Remove-Item -Path $_.Path -Force -WhatIf:$Params.SimulateDeletion }
    } else {

        # You could include additional checks to verify last backup, alert you if there should be more in there, etc...
    }

}
```

**Note:** Using the date extracted from the filename will be more accurate than the lastwritetime, which could be updated for other reasons (Since we have it, might as well use it.)

**Note 2 :** Added WhatIf in the `$params` so you can easily switch between actual removal and simulation (Theo's answer gave me the idea of providing that switch) and his `.Date` to make sure the date was set to midnight instead of  current time of day.

Answer (score 3):

In that case, you need to test how many files with a newer or equal date compared to the reference date there are in the folder. If less than 3, sort them by the LastWriteTime property and keep the top 3. If you have enough newer files left, you can delete the old ones:

```
$Folder  =  "C:\Backup"
$DateDel = (Get-Date).AddDays(-5).Date  # set to midnight

# get a list of all backup files
$allFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Filter 'archive*.bak' -File

# test how many of these are newer than 5 days ago
$latestFiles = @($allFiles | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge $DateDel })
if ($latestFiles.Count -lt 3) {
    # if less than three keep the latest 3 files and remove the rest
    $allFiles | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 3 | Remove-Item -WhatIf
}
else {
    # there are plenty of newer files, so we can remove the older ones
    $allFiles | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $DateDel } | Remove-Item -WhatIf
}
```

<sup>I have added the `-WhatIf` safety switch to both `Remove-Item` cmdlets, so you can first see what *would* happen before actualy destroying files. Once you are satisfied with what the console shows, remove those `-WhatIf` switches and run again</sup>

---

If you have 9 databases and the number in the filename after `archive_` makes the distinction between those database backup files, just put the above inside a loop and adjust the `-Filter`:

```
$Folder  = "C:\Backup"
$DateDel = (Get-Date).AddDays(-5).Date  # set to midnight
# loop through the 9 database files
for ($i = 1; $i -le 9; $i++) {
    # get a list of all backup files per database
    $allFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Filter "archive_$($i)_*.bak" -File

    # test how many of these are newer than 5 days ago
    $latestFiles = @($allFiles | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge $DateDel })
    if ($latestFiles.Count -lt 3) {
        # if less than three keep the latest 3 files and remove the rest
        $allFiles | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 3 | Remove-Item -WhatIf
    }
    else {
        # there are plenty of newer files, so we can remove the older ones
        $allFiles | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $DateDel } | Remove-Item -WhatIf
    }
}
```

---

Ok, so now we know the example names you gave do not bare resemblance with the *real* names, the code could be as simple as this:

```
$dbNames = 'archive', 'master', 'documents', 'rb'  # the names used in the backup files each database creates
$Folder  = "C:\Backup"
$DateDel = (Get-Date).AddDays(-5).Date  # set to midnight
# loop through the database files
foreach ($name in $dbNames) {
    # get a list of all backup files per database
    $allFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Filter "$($name)_*.bak" -File

    # test how many of these are newer than 5 days ago
    $latestFiles = @($allFiles | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge $DateDel })
    if ($latestFiles.Count -lt 3) {
        # if less than three keep the latest 3 files and remove the rest
        $allFiles | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 3 | Remove-Item -WhatIf
    }
    else {
        # there are plenty of newer files, so we can remove the older ones
        $allFiles | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $DateDel } | Remove-Item -WhatIf
    }
}
```

Comment: Theo, I have various DBs names, archive_1, archive_2 just an examples. I adjusted 4th line in first script to: "$allFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Filter '*.bak' -File". But if I advance time for one month and run it then remains only 3 files in total, e.g: test1_20022022.back, archive1_20022022.bak, archive2_20022022.bak. Remaing backups of  databases removed completely. In second script adjusted line and removed in -Filter "archive" part, left "-Filter "_$($i)_*.bak" -File". But it doesn't remove any files unfortunately.

Comment: @Vurdalag well, without knowing the realfile names, I could only go on what you wrote as example

Comment: @Vurdalag I take it the names you use in the comment are again just examples, but this time they ara inconsistent.. `test1_20022022.back`  needs filter `test$($i)_*.back`, while the others would use filter `archive$($i)_*.bak`. please show the real file names so I can give you a filter that would work.

Comment: can't I use general filter `*.bak` ? In this case I have to adopt filters to each file name. Real file names for current DBs: master_01022022.bak, archive_001_01022022.bak, archive_002_01022022.bak, arhive_003_01022022.bak, archive_004_01022022.bak, archive_005_01022022.bak, archive_006_01022022.bak, Documents_01022022.bak, rb_01022022.bak

Comment: @Vurdalag why didn't you give those names in the first place?? I could have made a far easier loop if I knew this. Now you led me believe the single digit determined the database but apparently your example names didn't look like the real thing at all. I don't think there is any point now in changing my code for you, although it would be a minor change..

Comment: @Vurdalag I have added new code to deal with the dbnames you now give in the filter

Comment: now you code is wokring as well. Didn't gave you DB names because on each server they are different names. Just thought about some unified approach. Thank you for your help.